# How to set a specific path while file uploading using php

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, filepath

I am new in PHP. i have a code for file uploading and save it in mysql. I want to set a specific path while uploading a file. For example i set the path

> C:\xampp\htdocs

and when ever i click on upload button my this directory will be open.

Here is my Code

```
  <?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="test123"; // Database name 
   $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(! $con)
    {
    die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("test123",$con);

    if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
        $errors= array();
        foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
            $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
            $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
            if($file_size > 2097152){
                $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
            }       
            $query="INSERT into upload_data (`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
            $desired_dir="user_data";
            if(empty($errors)==true){
                if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                    mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
                }
                if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
                }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                    $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                     rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
                }
             mysql_query($query);           
            }else{
                    print_r($errors);
            }
        }
        if(empty($error)){
            echo "Success";
        }
    }
    ?>


    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @AnkiiGangrade no i dont get any error. actually i want to know that how i can set a specific path while uploading my files.

Comment: your file uploading code is correct just change permission from 700 to 755. i think by the time you run code you already have created folder user_data so either delete or reassign access or change folder name for simplicity and give 755 permission in code.

Comment: @AnkiiGangrade Can u explain me briefly by changing in my code please. its my humble request to you.

Comment: @kamlesh.bar you said like that?  $desired_dir="C:\xampp\htdocs";
            if(empty($errors)==true){
                if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                    mkdir("$desired_dir", 0755);

Comment: nope.  it takes relative path in php for example if you are at C:\xampp\htdocs\testapp than by simply writting  $desired_dir="user_data"; will create folder at C:\xampp\htdocs\testapp\user_data .. if want move upword in directory and want to store there you can do $desired_dir="../user_data";

Comment: Also testapp must have writeable permission

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below :

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="root"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if(! $con)
{
die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("test",$con);

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       
        $query="INSERT into upload_data (`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
        $desired_dir="/home/test/www/uploads/user_datae";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0755);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
        mysql_query($query);           
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>


<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: its show error Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFirstWebsite\upload\up.php on line 28

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/home/test/www/uploads/user_datae/0Log.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFirstWebsite\upload\up.php on line 31

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php8AE4.tmp' to '/home/test/www/uploads/user_datae/0Log.txt' in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFirstWebsite\upload\up.php on line 31

Comment: Change the path. I have used a dummy path of my system `/home/test/www/uploads/user_datae`. You should use path as per your folder structure.

Comment: Use `C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFirstWebsite\upload\test`. Make sure `upload` has write permission.

Comment: @sunny : Its your path problem. I tested on my system and above code is working fine. Can you let me know the folder in `MyFirstWebsite`?

Comment: dear my problem is that when i upload a file i want to set my path is same every time. i dont want to browse file from i directory. i want to open direct location of file where it is places in my sytem. for example i have my all files in C:/MyFolder/test. i want that whenever i click on upload button my specif path will be open

Comment: @sunny : this is not possible by above code. `$desired_dir` is the path where you can upload the files. Its not related with browsing directory.

Comment: so sir what i can do for that? is there any help for me? please.

Comment: I don't think its correct approach. User should not have any restriction on browser folder. If you set any folder and it doesn't exists on any other user's system then that user will be bolcked.

Comment: Sir actually i want to set my g drive path which is common on all users of a  local network